# In C++, how does fscanf allocate memory address?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I am new to C++, and have been trying to figure out how fscanf allocates memory to the stack. I have written a piece of code that reads from a simple file and assigns the row values to an array. Then, I try to print out the address of each of the elements of the array.

```
values = (double *)calloc(rows*columns, sizeof(double));

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        fscanf(input, "%s", buffer);
        values[i*columns + j] = atof(buffer); 
    }
}


v = values;

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++){ 
        printf("at [%d, %d] value %g\n", i, j, values[i*columns + j]);
        printf("  address is 0x%x also 0x%x\n", &values[i*columns + j], 
            values + i*columns + j);

        printf("*v is = %g and v = 0x%x \n\n", *v, v);
        ++v; /* increment v by 1*/
    }
}
```

Suppose the input is a .txt file with a 1x3 matrix (vector) with entries `1 2 4`. I get the following result.

`at [0, 0] value 1
  address is 0xb51600 also 0xb51600
*v is = 1 and v = 0xb51600`

`at [0, 1] value 2
  address is 0xb51608 also 0xb51608
*v is = 2 and v = 0xb51608`

`at [0, 2] value 4
  address is 0xb51610 also 0xb51610
*v is = 4 and v = 0xb51610`

What I cannot understand is the fact the address jumps by 8 from [0,0] to [0,1], while it only jumps by 2 from [0,1] to [0,2]. According to what I read from C++ books, I thought the address should increment by the size of the type the array was declared. Can anyone provide some insights into this matter?

Thanks

Comment: fscanf is reading into `buffer`, whose declaration you don't show. It doesn't change, or "allocate" anything, it just requires buffer to have space already. But, why do you think a double scanned from a string and stored in an array, will keep some connection to the address of the string?

Comment: your output for the addresses are in hex. the addresses increment by 8 each time (`8 + 8 = 10` in hexadecimal)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I completely missed that. I'll try to keep an eye out for those kinds of mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I cannot understand is the fact the address jumps by 8 from [0,0] to [0,1], while it only jumps by 2 from [0,1] to [0,2].

No, that's another jump of 8.

Remember, this is hex!

```
0x10 - 0x08 = 0x08
  16 -    8 =    8
```

Answer (score 0):

Address jumps by 8 from [0,1] to [0,2] also because of HEX.

0xb51608 -> 0xb51609 -> 0xb5160A -> 0xb5160B -> 0xb5160C -> 0xb5160D -> 0xb5160E -> 0xb5160F -> 0xb51610

You can play fast with HEX arithmetic via Python for example:

```
$ python -c 'print 0xb51610 - 0xb51608'
8
```